# Please tell me if I did this calculus separation pretend algebra stuff all right

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Define $D_q=\frac{dD}{d_q}$

Is the following true or have I taken too many liberties with the Leibniz quasi-algebra?

$$\frac{dD_q}{dq}\frac{q}{D_q}=\frac{d}{dq}\frac{dD}{dq}\frac{dq}{dD}q=\frac{d}{dq}q=\frac{dq}{dq}=0$$

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{dq}{dq}=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. You need to parenthesize more carefully.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dD_q}{dq}\cdot\frac{q}{D_q} &= \left(\frac{d}{dq}\frac{dD}{dq}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{dq}{dD}\right)\cdot q \\
& \ne \frac{d}{dq} \left(\frac{dD}{dq}\cdot\frac{dq}{dD}\right)\cdot q.
\end{align}$$
You're trying to say that $\dfrac{dx}{dy}\cdot z = \dfrac{d(xz)}{dy}$, but that's not true. You can't simply rearrange what the differentiation operator applies to, any more than you can say $f(x)y = f(xy)$.